# Subdirectories and GCC problem with MakeFile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm writing a `makefile` for a very small personal project written in C.
My project is divided into subdirectories, but the directives for these utilme are not found even if (I think) the code is right:

```
TARGET = example.out

ENV = /usr/bin/env
MKDIR = mkdir
RMV = rm
CP = cp

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lm

BINDIR = ./bin
OBJDIR = ./obj
SRCDIR = ./src

SRCS = master.o request/request.o util/util.o # these are all .c files (./src/...)

# ---
.PHONY: build
build: prepare $(SRCS)
    $(ENV) $(CC) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS)) -o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

# ---
.PHONY: prepare
prepare:
    @$(ENV) $(MKDIR) -p $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    @$(ENV) $(CP) data.txt $(BINDIR)/data.txt

# ---
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(ENV) $(RM) -rf $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)

# ---
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(ENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

---

It says:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'master.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

And if I change `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c` to `%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c`, it says:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'request/request.o', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

Comment: `-lm` should not be in CFLAGS, it should be in `LDLIBS`.  If you use the right names, implicit rules will work much better.

Comment: I wonder why you have `$(ENV)` before each command.  I've not seen that done and don't see any benefit from doing it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've seen it used like this and so I used it like this, in the end it doesn't improve anything, it doesn't make anything worse.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for the advice, i will fix it.

Comment: I'm intrigued that you've seen it.  In 30+ years of using make, I've not seen it used like that (though I don't think `env` even existed at the start).   However, I agree that it does no harm, even though I don't think it does anything useful.  It certainly is not part of your problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I take this into consideration, and I will remove "ENV" in the working version, thanks.

Comment: The presence of `$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS))` in your build recipe should be a big red flag.  It shows that you are relying on different files than the ones declared as the rule's dependencies.  The mismatch between the declared and actual dependencies is in fact near the center of your issue: you have rules for building the actual dependencies, but these do not apply to the declared dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have effectively *no* rule to create `master.o` from `master.c`.

In the following rule:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
```

`./obj/%.o` does not match `master.o`

And if `master.c` is in `src` (as indicated by the comment) the default rules don't match either.

So in order to match the rule, the target must be `./obj/master.o`

The same goes for all the other .o files and you will run into trouble with the subdirectories. To get around that you can create the target directory in the recipe directly:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CC) -c -o $@  $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Answer (score 0):

the default behaviour of gcc is to place the .o-file beneath the .c-file. to place it into the object file directory, you have to use an `-o $@` argument:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(ENV) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

And the build rule shoud depend on `$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS))`
if this is what is used in the command.

```
build: prepare $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS))
    $(ENV) $(CC) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SRCS)) -o $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed. I think is related to rule declaration.

Comment: oh yes you are right, this is another issue - build needs to depend on something like objdir/master.o, as the plain master.o will never exist